# maximize a div & change its fontSize

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size, maximize

I have 2 divs in my html and I want to increase the size by onclick, but the fontSize doesn't change.

Code:

```js
function changeSize(id, weight, height)
{
with (document)
{
 if (getElementById(id).style.width = '240px'){
  getElementById(id).style.width = weight + 'px';
  getElementById(id).style.height = height + 'px';
  getElementById(id).style.fontSize = '30px';
 } 
 else {
  getElementById(id).style.width ='240px';
  getElementById(id).style.height ='300px';
  getElementById(id).style.fontSize = '18px';

 }
}
}
```

```css
.kaesten{
 width:240px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:darkgrey;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000;
 border: 5px solid #F0F8ff;
 vertical-align:top;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #777;
 float:left;
 margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="kaesten" onclick="maxi('box1', 600, 600); return false;">
test1

</div>

<div id="box2" class="kaesten">
test2
</div>
```

Question: How can I change the fontSize? And how can I change the div size into the original size again by a second click?

Comment: Try `getElementByID(id).style.fontSize = '30px';`

Comment: try getElementById(id).style.fontSize = '30' +'px';

Comment: Mistake was ID instead of Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a typo. Properties and methods in JavaScript are case-sensetive. The method is `getElementById`, not `getElementByID`.

Assuming the only inline styles that are on the element are the ones you add in the function above, you can use the following to remove the styles and 'reset' the element:

```js
function changeSize(id, weight, height){
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if(elem.getAttribute('style')){
        elem.removeAttribute('style');
    } else {
        elem.style.width = weight + 'px';
        elem.style.height = height + 'px';
        elem.style.fontSize = '30px';
    }
}

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('kaesten');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].onclick = function(){
        changeSize(this.id, 600, 600);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="kaesten">test1</div>
<div id="box2" class="kaesten">test2</div>
```

Even better would be to simply pass the element to the function as a reference, rather than passing the elements `id` and having to query the document again.

Comment: I thought of an if function, edited it above. Or is that no good programming?

Comment: Thanks, it works :) but why do I need to delete the style attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do in this case is to use 2 css classes and switch those with javascript. on each click you can check if it has a certain class and then switch those

```
.normal{
    width:240px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:darkgrey;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000;
    border: 5px solid #F0F8ff;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #777;
    float:left;
    margin-left:30px;
}

.maximize{
    width:4800px;
    height:600px;
    font-size:30px;
    background-color:darkgrey;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000;
    border: 5px solid #F0F8ff;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #777;
    float:left;
    margin-left:30px;
}
```

You can switch with:

```
var class = document.getElementById("MyElement").className;
if(class === "normal"){
     document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "maximize";
} else {
     document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "normal";
}
```

Comment: I would like to do it in JS, something like that?                               function changeSize(id, weight, height)
{
 with (document)
 {
  if (getElementById(id).style.width = '240px'){
   getElementById(id).style.width = weight + 'px';
   getElementById(id).style.height = height + 'px';
   getElementById(id).style.fontSize = '30px';
  } 
  else {
   getElementById(id).style.width ='240px';
   getElementById(id).style.height ='300px';
   getElementById(id).style.fontSize = '18px';

  }
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

typo error

```
getElementById(id).style.fontSize = '30' +'px';
             ^
```

Please check it's working

```js
function maxi(id, weight, height)
{
 with (document)
 {
  getElementById(id).style.width = weight + 'px';
  getElementById(id).style.height = height + 'px';
  getElementById(id).style.fontSize = '30' +'px';
  
 }
}
```

```css
.kaesten{
 width:240px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:darkgrey;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000;
 border: 5px solid #F0F8ff;
 vertical-align:top;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #777;
 float:left;
 margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="kaesten" onclick="maxi('box1', 600, 600); return false;">
test1

</div>

<div id="box2" class="kaesten">
test2
</div>
```